# Im making my first encryption program, any tips?

Tags: c#, encryption, cryptography

Im making a program in C# that has passwords and I need to encrypt them. So far I flip the string backwards (so hello becomes olleh) and then I use a loop that loops through each character, and the loop inside it loops through another string that has the converted letters to see if they match. Using this, hello = Ghh#$ so it works fine. So anyway, are there any extra stuff I can add to it? PS what is salting and how is hashing one way?

Comment: The first encryption rule - don't invent your own algorythms

Comment: Is this for a learning experience or actually to use? And as for salt and hash, just google those terms.

Comment: they're only for education, so thats why im writing my own

Comment: I can't answer all your questions, but I can say that salting is used to prevent rainbow table attacks.

Comment: @Efe Ozturkoglu: what are you learning? Just go with http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Caesar_cipher - it is trivial, but at least well-known algorythm

Comment: I cannot agree with @zerkms enough.

Comment: The first encryption rule - don't take advice on encryption from strangers on the internet, myself included. Remember that we are not all good-meaning, bunnies-and-unicorns-kind strangers :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First off, the difference between encryption and hashing is, at a high level, that encrypted data can be decrypted with the right key, whereas hashed data cannot be retrieved except via brute force methods like pregeneration or rainbow tables.

Hashed passwords are validated by hashing the user's input each time that they log in in the same way that you do when they create the account, and comparing the result of the hash.  For any given input, the hashed result should be the same.

**Obligatory rant:**

There is a good argument to be made that passwords should *always* be hashed using a cryptographically-strong algorithm.  You may hear the excuse that "my application/web page/etc is not all that important, there is no sensitive information there", or "I'm just learning so it isn't important", but the fact is that if I can crack the security of one website, or you leave your machine logged in and I steal your password file from your "educational" app, I can take all of the user's email addresses and virtually guarantee that at least a few of them will use the same password for that gmail or yahoo account.  I can then send reset requests for just about any site that their email tells me they have an account for and get access to those also.  **So it is very important that no matter what software you are writing, if it stores passwords, you should do the responsible thing and salt + hash them properly**.

Answer (score 7):

Rule one of cryptography is don't write your own encryption scheme. Instead use a library such as http://www.cryptlib.com/why-use-cryptlib-10-good-reasons which has bindings for C#.

For more information check out the first answer to:
https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/2202/lessons-learned-and-misconceptions-regarding-encryption-and-cryptology

Comment: +1 I was just about to link to the same "lessons learned" article.

Answer (score 3):

Salt:  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Salt_(cryptography)
Hashing:  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cryptographic_hash_function

Simplistic Example:

```
var salt = "abc123";
var encryptedPassword = HashingAlgorithm("password");
var encryptedSaltedPassword = HashingAlgorithm ("password" + salt);

Console.Writeline(encryptedPassword);
Console.Writeline(encryptedSaltedPassword);
```

writes out

```
aIdekXieklKq309nasdf

dfk#cxk)8lkdfesijcde
```

The point of salting your code is to prevent dictionary attacks.  If anyone figures out your HashingAlgorithm, they can brute-force run through every word in the dictionary and figure out that "password" hashes to be "aIdekXieklKq309nasdf".  If you salt your to-be-encrypted words, they'd have to know your salt word too.

Also, it's good to hash your passwords into a database instead of using some two-way algorithm, that way anyone (including you and your co-workers) having access to the database can look and see what your users use as passwords (since a lot of users tend to reuse the same passwords on multiple sites).

Comment: "The point of salting your code is to prevent dictionary attacks" --- not precisely true. The salting prevents of using pre-calculated hashes. And the source for the pre-calculation could be a dictionary as well as just a brute force

Comment: Typically the salt should be something user-specific, like the username associated with the password, not a constant.